# switch between two surfaceView

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I have two surfaceView, only one of them added to the view hierachy at a time, the other one is removed, my problem is, when an surfaceView added, there's a instant black rect cover it, can I avoid this?

here's the testing code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {   
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView1;
    private SurfaceHolder.Callback mSurfaceCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rv = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) this.getWindow().getDecorView()
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        mSurfaceView1= new SurfaceView(this);
        mSurfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Canvas c = null;
                try
                {
                        c = holder.lockCanvas();
                        c.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
                        Paint p = new Paint();
                        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        Rect r = new Rect(100, 50, 300, 250);
                        c.drawRect(r, p);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
        };
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);
        mSurfaceView1.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);

        Button b = new Button(this);b.setText("view1");
        Button c = new Button(this);c.setText("view2");
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                    ll.addView(mSurfaceView);
                    ll.removeView(mSurfaceView1);
                }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        });

        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                    ll.addView(mSurfaceView1);
                    ll.removeView(mSurfaceView);
                }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        });

        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ll.addView(b, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.addView(c, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        frameLayout.addView(ll);
    }
}
```

Comment: go for TextureView to avoid that blink http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html

Comment: Thanks Braj, it really help. another question, If I want to display the SurfaceTexture generated from TextureView, I need a singleton SurfaceView, right? and draw all the pixel from SurfaceTexture to Surface in SurfaceView? What if the content of SurfaceTexture change frequently, the copying pixels operation may consume too much cpu.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have much idea about all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the two surfaceviews when you call `onCreate`, and switch their status in `onClick`. like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rv = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) this.getWindow().getDecorView()
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        mSurfaceView1= new SurfaceView(this);
        mSurfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Canvas c = null;
                try
                {
                        c = holder.lockCanvas();
                        c.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
                        Paint p = new Paint();
                        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        Rect r = new Rect(100, 50, 300, 250);
                        c.drawRect(r, p);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
        };
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);
        mSurfaceView1.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);

        Button b = new Button(this);b.setText("view1");
        Button c = new Button(this);c.setText("view2");
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
//                    ll.addView(mSurfaceView);
//                    ll.removeView(mSurfaceView1);
                    mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mSurfaceView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        });

        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
//                    ll.addView(mSurfaceView1);
//                    ll.removeView(mSurfaceView);
                    mSurfaceView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        });

        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ll.addView(b, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.addView(c, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // add mSurfaceView & mSurfaceView1
        ll.addView(mSurfaceView);
        ll.addView(mSurfaceView1);
        mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mSurfaceView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        frameLayout.addView(ll);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your instant reply! View.GONE did resolve my problem, since these two SurafceView not dettached from the view hierachy, is it too much consumption? In fact in my condition, there maybe 10 or more surfaceViews.

Comment: every surfaceview just has one copy which is created in onCreate(). switching status costs less than frequently adding and removing surfaceview.